# magento 1.8.1 /images/catalog/product/placeholder/ after customers logged

Tags: magento

my problem is that when a client is authenticated and goes into a product page, instead of the product image is the image placeholder. If you surf the same page without being authenticated but I see the correct image. 
Who can help me? 
thank you very much

others settings:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M                              

chmod -R 777 media/
```

**correct path :** `/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/0/e0467_1205.jpg`

**incorrect path:** `/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using https on the authenticated pages? In that case you could link with  //media/etc... or use `_secure => true`, for example:

```
<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/etc..', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as soon as I get home I try, although I do not think that is the problem because on some products I see the correct image and on others I see the placeholder. 
According You can depend on the size of the images? 
But if so, should not I see it in both cases 
However, as soon as I try, I'll update

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work. 
Do you have ideas??

Comment: Unfortunatly I have not. Maybe you could post the code where you load the images with some debugging?